# Database mapping by column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I have a list of database tables that all work together based on column names and field values.

I am able to pull up about 3/4 of the tables with a simple primary ID column field value match.

With the tables that I'm able to pull up currently, I would like to be able to retrieve the rest of the data based on possibly column matching across the tables.

I have started an Idea.. But I am not quite sure how to complete the process.

This website is using WordPress, but ideally, this could still very well be done with straight PHP, without using the WordPress database class.

**Retrieve all the information about the school:**
`$school = $this->get_school('129020');`

**Function:** (`$this->get_school($id);`)

```
private function get_school($id){
    global $wpdb;
    /* Retrieve the IPEDS database tables. */
    $columns = $this->map_database('iped');
    /* Retrieve the initial results by the UNITID. */
    $data = array();
    foreach($columns['UNITID']['shared_tables'] as $table){
        $data[$table] = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT *
            FROM `{$table}`
            WHERE `UNITID` = '{$id}';
            ", 
            ARRAY_A
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Function:** (`$this->map_database($database_table)`)

```
private function map_database($database_table = 'all'){
    global $wpdb;
    /* Get all of the database tables. */
    $tables = $wpdb->get_results('SHOW TABLES', ARRAY_N);
    $table_columns = array();
    foreach($tables as $table){
        if($database_table != 'all'){
            /* Filter tables by partial string matching the table name. */
            if(stripos($table[0], $database_table) === false){
                continue;
            }
        }
        /* Get all of the columns available in each database table. */
        $columns = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT *
            FROM   information_schema.columns
            WHERE  table_name = '{$table[0]}'
            ORDER  BY ordinal_position  
            ",
            ARRAY_A
        );
        for($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++){
            $column = $columns[$i];
            /* Don't overwrite any data. Could result in missing or overlapping of data? */
            if(isset($table_columns[$table[0]]) && in_array($column['COLUMN_NAME'], $table_columns[$table[0]])){
                continue;
            }
            $table_columns[$table[0]][] = $column['COLUMN_NAME'];
        }
    }
    return $this->map_database_tables($tables, $table_columns);
}
```

**Function:** (`$this->map_database_tables($database_tables, $database_consolidated);`)

```
/* 
$database_tables - Array consisting of strictly database tables. 
$database_consolidated - Nested array consisting of: table_name => table_columns
*/      
private function map_database_tables($database_tables, $database_consolidated){
    if(empty($database_tables) || empty($database_consolidated)){
        return;
    }
    $common_columns = array();

    foreach($database_consolidated as $table_name => $table_columns){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($table_columns); $i++){
            $table_column = $table_columns[$i];
            /* Find similar table columns in other database tables. */
            $search = $this->search_database_tables($database_consolidated, $table_column);
            if(!empty($search)){
                foreach($search as $column => $table){
                    $common_columns[$table_column]['shared_tables'] = $table;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $common_columns;
}
```

**Function:** (`$this->search_database_tables($tables, $column_name);`)

```
/* Returns column name and database tables sharing the column name. */
private function search_database_tables($tables, $column_name){
    $common_tables = array();
    foreach($tables as $table_name => $table_columns){
        if(in_array($column_name, $table_columns)){
            $common_tables[$column_name][] = $table_name;
        }
    }
    return $common_tables;
}
```

**Results in an array in the following format:**

```
$database_map = array(
    'table_name' => array(
        'row_number' => array(
            'field_key' => 'field_value'
        )
    )
);
```

Where I'm puzzled is what to do next? Where do I go with this?

I have all the data at my fingers tips, but I'm just stumped what to do next.

Here's what I was thinking, but definitely need some guidance or input.....

I would like to check the values of the other table columns. So if for example, I am looking up a secondary ID number, which only exists in one of the other tables that hasn't already been pulled up by the primary ID number.

Table 1 might have a column called 'Secondary' and a field value of '123'.

I would like to cycle through all of the other database tables, to see if a column 'Secondary' exists. If it does, then pull all of the fields from that table, based on the matching column name and field value of the two table field values for that column name.

I'm sure my code is absolutely horrible and could probably be significantly simplified. I have looked for some existing frameworks which might already achieve my desired goal. I've had no such luck in finding anything.

I am open for advice in where to go next with my code. I am also open for any existing frameworks that I could use.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to do this in PHP and not mysql joins?

Comment: you COULD just set up some foreign keys in MySQL and query the information_schema DB to get those key definitions in PHP to build your join queries dynamically... question is, why would you want to? This system would collapse if ever you ever use a single name for two+ different purposes - the system would happily join those two+ tables, but one+ of them will be wrong.